# how to update into mysql database using checkbox

Tags: jquery, mysql, ajax, database

I have first 8 checkbox’s and each checkbox’s created different color’s id names,  like this… see (html sample code)..
I also wrote code in jquery, If any checkbox checked it will show div with color background from ID color name if unchecked it will hide that color div box.

Due to I’m NEW In Ajax, and recently started learn, but need help…  how can write ajax and update database code to allow UPDATE into database not INSERT it, and once update, automatic show div color background or hide, depend on checkbox from database.
And which way is best, 0 and 1 or, true or false, or etc…
Many thanks.

```
<div class="checkbox">
        <label class="checkbox">
         <input name="checkbox" id="blue-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="blue"/>
         blue
        </label>
       </div>
       <div class="checkbox">
        <label class="checkbox">
         <input name="checkbox" id="green-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="green"/>
         green
        </label>
       </div>
       <div class="checkbox">
        <label class="checkbox">
         <input name="checkbox" id="yellow-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="yellow"/>
         yellow
        </label>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group ">
      <label class="control-label ">
       Check all that apply
      </label>
      <div class=" ">
       <div class="checkbox">
        <label class="checkbox">
         <input name="checkbox1" id="orange-checkbox"  type="checkbox" value="orange"/>
         orange
        </label>
       </div>
       <div class="checkbox">
        <label class="checkbox">
         <input name="checkbox1" id="purple-checkbox"  type="checkbox" value="red"/>
         purple
        </label>
       </div>
       <div class="checkbox">
        <label class="checkbox">
         <input name="checkbox1" id="black-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="black"/>
         black
        </label>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
```

in jquery ...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
        if($(this).attr("value")=="red"){
            $("#red").toggle();
        }
        if($(this).attr("value")=="green"){
            $("#green").toggle();
        }
        if($(this).attr("value")=="blue"){
            $("#blue").toggle();
        }
             if($(this).attr("value")=="yellow"){
            $("#yellow").toggle();
        }
        if($(this).attr("value")=="orange"){
            $("#orange").toggle();
        }
        if($(this).attr("value")=="black"){
            $("#black").toggle();
        }

    });
});
```

Comment: ajax is just an http request performed in the background of the page, on behalf of code. that's it. it's nothing "special". It's nothing "magical". it's just an http request. the data going client->browser is basically identical, whether you use ajax to submit it or just clicked a "submit" button.

Comment: that is what i need to submit button to update into database and show or hide div, but not sure how to write that code. doe any can help.

Comment: which part? show/hide the div? or update the database? the show/hide is easy. `$('form').on('submit', function() { $('#yourdiv').toggle(); });`

Comment: show hide is easy part but to update into database, i'm having trouble how to write that code to allow show and hide div...